# Improve query to join other tables depending on value without union

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I have a table containing the following data:

```
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+-----+------------------------+---------------------+
| notification_id | from_user_id | from_user_auth_level | to_user_id | to_user_auth_level | status_id | type | subject | message | url | timestamp_inserted_utc | timestamp_read_utc  |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+-----+------------------------+---------------------+
|               1 | NULL         | NULL                 |          1 |                  1 |         0 |    2 | test    | test    | url | 2010-10-10 00:00:00    | 2011-10-10 00:00:00 |
|               2 | 2            | 5                    |          1 |                  1 |         0 |    2 | test    | test    | url | 2010-10-10 00:00:00    | 2011-10-10 00:00:00 |
|               3 | 3            | 5                    |          1 |                  1 |         0 |    2 | test    | test    | url | 2010-10-10 00:00:00    | 2011-10-10 00:00:00 |
|               4 | 2295         | 4                    |          1 |                  1 |         0 |    2 | test    | test    | url | 2010-10-10 00:00:00    | 2011-10-10 00:00:00 |
|               5 | 10           | 1                    |          1 |                  1 |         0 |    2 | test    | test    | url | 2010-10-10 00:00:00    | 2011-10-10 00:00:00 |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+-----+------------------------+---------------------+
```

And then I have some other tables like 'users', 'companies', 'organizations', ... etc.

I need to be able to get the username, gender and image of every notification (based on the from_user_id and from_user_auth_level).

But the problem resides in the fact, that this info resides in different places, depending on what the user_auth_level is.

For example: if my user is a "regular" user, his auth_level will be 1. And the image will reside in my "users" table, and the gender is applicable. 
But if the user has auth_level == 5, it means he is an organization. In this case, gender is not applicable, and the image resides in the "organization" table, this needs to be linked via users to user_roles and then to the organization.

And this goes on for every user type, they all require different joins.

I have created a working query, but this uses UNION's everywhere, and I have read that it is not the best to use for performance reasons, so i'm hoping someone can guide me to improving this query with performance in mind:

```
                SELECT n.*, NULL as username, NULL as gender, NULL as picture
                FROM notification as n
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level IS NULL
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid
                UNION
                SELECT n.*, u.username, u.gender as gender, u.profile_picture as picture
                FROM notification as n
                LEFT JOIN users AS u ON n.from_user_id = u.user_id
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level = 1
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid
                UNION
                SELECT n.*, u.username, NULL as gender, c.logo as picture
                FROM notification as n
                LEFT JOIN users AS u ON n.from_user_id = u.user_id
                LEFT JOIN user_companies AS uc on u.user_id = uc.user_id
                LEFT JOIN company as c on uc.company_id = c.company_id
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level = 4
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid
                UNION
                SELECT n.*, u.username, NULL as gender, o.logo as picture
                FROM notification as n
                LEFT JOIN users AS u ON n.from_user_id = u.user_id
                LEFT JOIN user_roles as ur on u.user_id = ur.user_id
                LEFT JOIN organization as o on ur.org_id = o.org_id
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level = 5
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid
                UNION
                SELECT n.*, u.username, NULL as gender, o.logo as picture
                FROM notification as n
                LEFT JOIN users AS u ON n.from_user_id = u.user_id
                LEFT JOIN user_roles as ur on u.user_id = ur.user_id
                LEFT JOIN organization as o on ur.org_id = o.org_id
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level = 7
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid
                UNION
                SELECT n.*, u.username, NULL as gender, NULL as picture
                FROM notification as n
                LEFT JOIN users AS u ON n.from_user_id = u.user_id
                WHERE n.from_user_auth_level = 9
                AND n.to_user_id = $userid"
```

After I get this result, I use PHP to order the results based on the timestamp_inserted_utc, since it's not possible to get the correct results with the UNION.

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE n.from_user_auth_level IS NULL OR n.from_user_auth_level IN(1,4,5,7)`. i would suggest you simplify the problem, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the notification table as base and used conditional outer joins as:

```
select 
  n.*,t1.gender, t2.orgNo 
from 
  notifications n
left outer join table1 t1 on (n.auth=1 and more join)
left outer join table2 t2 on (n.auth=2 and more..)
```

You will have more columns but their name would make sense and you may merge at application level.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested indexes (most are "covering"):

```
n:  (from_user_auth_level, to_user_id, from_user_id)
u:  (user_id, username, profile_picture, gender)
o:  (org_id, logo)
ur:  (org_id, user_id)
c:  (company_id, logo)
uc:  (company_id, user_id)
```

(They may even speed up Teson's Answer.)